# actionButton fires twice

Tags: r, shiny

I have a very large application with many actionButtons triggering events.  I use the following logic for all my actionButtons in server.R:

```
observe({
  if(input$myButton==0) return(NULL)
  isolate({
  # Code goes here
  })
})
```

At some stage recently, the code within the isolate({}) now triggers twice whenever I click the actionButton.

It happens on all buttons within my project - and I can't think of how to debug it.  Can anyone offer advice on debugging or what to look for?

Comment: It's almost impossible to diagnose without having a self-contained minimal example, and even more because it is is intermittent. Try to remove everything in your code not required to reproduce the error.

Comment: I rolled back my code and re-coded a week's work, and now I don't get the problem.  I am certain it was to do with using actionButtons, but creating them within a uiOutput. I had actionButtons triggering an updateTabsetPanel() event, which I think in turn re-rendered the buttons, thus triggering the observe({}) a second time.  Similar to [this problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/e4bGcKOs5QM).  Thanks for everyone's input.

Comment: I had this problem today and for reference purposes for others I will post the reason for the problem. My observe was accidentally nested within another observe, this meant that it would run multiple times depending on the number of instances the outer observe had run already (duplicating the observe code each time the outer observe was run).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For debugging purposes you could use reactive log visualizer and showcase mode:

- Start with a fresh R session and run the command `options(shiny.reactlog=TRUE)`
- Then run your app in a show case mode: `runApp("yourApp", display.mode = "showcase")`
- At any time you can hit Ctrl+F3 (or for Mac users, Command+F3) in your web browser to launch the reactive log visualization.